# codeigniter: how to transform array value from specify index?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i have an array like this

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#20 
      (4) { 
           ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
           ["name"]=> string(6) "robert" 
           ["height"]=> string(3) "165" 
           ["weight"]=> string(2) "81" } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#21 
      (4) { 
           ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
           ["name"]=> string(4) "mike" 
           ["height"]=> string(3) "175" 
           ["weight"]=> string(2) "69" } }
```

so, I want to change my array values.

for example i want to change all value from `["height"]` and `["weight"]`. I categorize height and weight in the form of numbers like this:

`height`

`1` = `150` .......... `170`

`2` = `171` .......... `190`

`weight`

`1` = `50` ........... `70`

`2` = `71` ........... `80`

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#20 
      (4) { 
           ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
           ["name"]=> string(6) "robert" 
           ["height"]=> string(1) "1" 
           ["weight"]=> string(1) "2" } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#21 
      (4) { 
           ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
           ["name"]=> string(4) "mike" 
           ["height"]=> string(1) "2" 
           ["weight"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

my array is `dynamic` so that value can change anytime. of course `["name"]` will not change at all because I did not give categorization. can you help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean that your array is `dynamic`? and is the array build from a database?

Comment: yes, i call from database. after that, i want to transform array value without change anything in database @Lupin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example array to be:

```
//example people array
$people = [
      //robert
      (object)[
            "id" =>"1",
            "name"=> "robert",
            "height" => "165", 
            "weight" => "79",
            ],

      //mike
      (object)[
        "id" => "2",
        "name"=> "mike",
        "height"=> "175", 
        "weight" =>"69",
        ]
  ];
```

You could walk the array and modify each object after a little comparison. Note im not checking all possible ranges to keep this concise (it should be just a couple more checks)

```
//walk the array 
array_walk($people, function($person){

  //test height and assign category
  if($person->height <= 190 && $person->height > 170)
    $person->height = "2";
  else
    $person->height = "1";

  //test weight and assign category
  if($person->weight <= 80 && $person->weight > 70)
    $person->weight = "2";
  else
    $person->weight = "1";
});
```

Which produces the desired result you can check live [here](http://phpepl.cloudcontrolled.com?code=%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fthe%20example%20people%20array%0D%0A%24people%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Frobert%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(object)%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%20%3D%3E%221%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3D%3E%20%22robert%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22height%22%20%3D%3E%20%22165%22%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22weight%22%20%3D%3E%20%2281%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fmike%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(object)%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%20%3D%3E%20%222%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3D%3E%20%22mike%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22height%22%3D%3E%20%22175%22%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22weight%22%20%3D%3E%2269%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%2F%2Fwalk%20the%20array%20%0D%0Aarray_walk(%24people%2C%20function(%24person)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2Ftest%20height%20and%20assign%20category%0D%0A%20%20if(%24person-%3Eheight%20%3C%3D%20190%20%26%26%20%24person-%3Eheight%20%3E%20170)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24person-%3Eheight%20%3D%20%222%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24person-%3Eheight%20%3D%20%221%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2Ftest%20weight%20and%20assign%20category%0D%0A%20%20if(%24person-%3Eweight%20%3C%3D%2080%20%26%26%20%24person-%3Eweight%20%3E%2070)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24person-%3Eweight%20%3D%20%222%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24person-%3Eweight%20%3D%20%221%22%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%0D%0Aprint_r(%24people)%3B) (CTRL+ENTER to run)

Comment: woooww!! this is what I was looking for! you've saved my life @JSelser !

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array callback function like `array_map`

```
function changeMe($itemArr) {
    foreach($itemArr as $key=>$value) {
        if($key == "a") {
            $itemArr[$key] = "newVal";  
        }
    }

    return $itemArr;
}

$myArray = array(
                0=>array(
                    "a"=>"1", 
                    "b"=>"2"
                ), 
                1=>array(
                    "a"=>"1", 
                    "b"=>"44"
                    )
                );

$myArray = array_map("changeMe", $myArray);

var_dump($myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_walk()` if you want to change in current array else use `array_filter()` if you want to produce a new array,

Note that any of them will not change your value in database unless you execute any query.

Using `array_walk()`,

```
$array = array(); // your input array here

array_walk( $array, function(&$v){
    ( $v->height > 149 && $v->height < 171 ) ? ( $v->height = 1 ) : ( $v->height = 2 );
    ( $v->weight > 49 && $v->weight < 71 ) ? ( $v->weight = 1 ) : ( $v->weight = 2 );
});
```

Using `array_filter()`,

```
$array = array(); // your input array here

$your_new_array = array_filter( $array, function($v){
    ( $v->height > 149 && $v->height < 171 ) ? ( $v->height = 1 ) : ( $v->height = 2 );
    ( $v->weight > 49 && $v->weight < 71 ) ? ( $v->weight = 1 ) : ( $v->weight = 2 );
    return true;
});
```

Comment: thank you my friend @Viral , my problem is solved. your code is same like JSelser 's code, but I really appreciate because you've helped answer my question.

Comment: glad to be of help! I just wanted to make `array_filter` and `array_walk` clear. :)